# Pass data from one library to another library to application using delegate

Tags: c#, events, delegates

CameraManager.dll will be statically linked to the application. There is a camera dll(MyCam1.dll) which will be loaded dynamically as per selected camera.

I want image to be transferred to main application. I am not sure how to register delegate in CameraManager.dll! and do I need to write another delegate to transfer image from cameramanager.dll to application?

lib1:CameraManager.dll

```
public Interface ICamera
{
 void InitCam();
 void CloseCam();
 void SetGain();
 void SetBrightness();
}

public class CameraCollection
{
   public void createCamInstance()
   {
        ICamera Camob = instance.InitCam();     
   }
   //load library dynamically.
   public void LoadCamera()
   {
       Assembly DLL = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\MyCam*.dll");
       foreach (Type type in DLL.GetTypes())
       {
            if (type.FullName == "Mycam")
            {
                instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); 
            }                                                   
       }
   }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

lib2: MyCam1.dll

```
public delegate void ImageGrabDone(byte[] data);

public class Mycam:ICamera{
     public event ImageGrabDone GrabEvent;

     void ICamera.InitCam()
     {
          //some initialization stuff
     }
     void ImageGrabbed()
     {
      // This function will be called automatically when camera gets triggered.    
      //from Here I want to pass Image/byte[] to CameraManager.dll and from CameraManager to 
      //host application.
     }
}
```